# accessing secret from google secret manager

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-secret-manager

I put a serviceAccount.json in google secret manager, and I want to build am api service by Fastapi, a python web framework.

I mounted secret as a disk ,I want to read it from my file,but it reply no such file....plz anyone help me?

[image: app.py]

[image: Dockerfile]
[image: secret mount setting]

Comment: Never store JSON service account keys in Google Secret Manager. If your workload is running in Cloud Run, you should use the machine identity to grant permissions https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never store JSON service account keys in Google Secret Manager. If your workload is running in Cloud Run, you should use the service identity to grant permissions https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity.

Comment: But I do need this file to access firestore. How do I access firestore without serviceAccount key json file ?

Comment: You can use ADC. WHen you are on a Google Cloud service, you have a service account (default or user defined). And the Client libraries discover it automatically and use it by default. Simply grant that service account to access the ressources that you want!